# Print charts in new tab

Tags: jquery, highcharts, export

Hi Guys I am using high charts and I wanted to export a high charts in new window or tab. Consider a scenario: whenever I click on a print charts option a popup window that comes up, e.g. Print Preview. What I want is want that popup i.e Print Preview to open in a new tab instead.

Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Here goes my code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                         'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0,
                   135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }],

        navigation: {
            buttonOptions: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        exporting: {
            format:"print"
        }
    });

    // button handler
    $('#button-export').click(function () {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        chart.exportChart();
    });
});
```

Comment: this also isn't working as i am new to high charts but i have done something like this so this is for reference

Comment: if you dont know how to export chart on your server please check this post <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/26423402/1262764">highchart export</a>

Comment: that's not the problem in my local i am able to export the charts the way highchart library provided but i am not been able to export in new tab. appreciate your response and time

Comment: Have you tried something like this: instead of exporting chart, open the same chart in a new tab (nothing to do with Highcharts, I guess). Then on that tab create the same chart and in callback use `chart.exportChart()` to export chart.

Comment: it will be tideous another approached that i;ve tried is on click of print button i am opening a new window and then in new window i use function written in parent window that will print the high charts


here's flow :
1. click on button and opens up a new window
2. call parent window function by using window.parent

but some how css's are not rendering properly

Answer (score 2):

You need to use formAttributes in the exporting:

```
formAttributes: {
            target: '_blank'
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dWfv5/10/